# connection closed unexpectedly in vnc viewer while using jenkins image in docker compose file

Tags: docker, jenkins, docker-compose, vnc-viewer

I am using simple docker-compose file to pull jenkins image. I am able to create the container, but when i try to access it through VNC viewer then i am facing connection closed unexpectedly

I am trying to connect with 127.0.0.1:2050 in vnc viewer which is the port mentioned in compose file.

Docker-compose file:

```
version: '3'
services:
  Jenkins:
    image: jenkins/jenkins
    ports:
      - 2050:5900
```

It says connection closed unexpectedly. But it should actually display the container which is created[Docker-compose file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HYerC.png)

[VNC error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fwc96.png)

Comment: Is there a reason why you cannot just access Jenkins with your browser?

Comment: No specific reason. I need to modify host details in container which would be easy if i directly login to it.

Comment: It's better to modify host settings directly on build time of the Docker image, then you could just run the container and login directly to Jenkins with your browser. Configuring host settings in a running container is against the whole idea of ephemeral containers :)

Comment: Alright. Thank you :) But i am trying to understand if i am doing something wrong in compose file for which i am getting this connection closed error.

Comment: Setting up VNC with Docker seems to come with a little bit more necessary effort. [This](https://qxf2.com/blog/view-docker-container-display-using-vnc-viewer/) seems to be a useful blog post on how to do this.

Comment: Actually i have done this VNC with dockers setup for selenium grid and its absolutely working fine and i am able to access all docker machines. But not sure what i am missing in this jenkins setup.

Comment: I cannot answer that, as I haven't used VNC before. But I also don't really get what you're trying to achieve. :D Why don't you just map port 8080:8080 and then access Jenkins at localhost:8080? They have a very good [documentation](https://github.com/jenkinsci/docker/blob/master/README.md) here.

Comment: Thanks! Right now i am accessing the same way you mentioned:) But I wanted take some inputs from folks who are experts in docker compose and VNC :)